# SQL to Pivot a single Row to make new column names for data

Tags: sql

So the main issue I have is being victim to a poorly constructed table in sql, but since I am not allowed to refactor it I am trying to figure out how to parse the data in SQL.  Currently I am using SQL to dump the raw data and then sticking it into another program to manipulate.  Is it possible to do it all in SQL?  The tables are similar to the below picture.  Essentially a couple parts to it, I know how to do a few parts individually but cannot figure out how to stitch it all together.  Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Example Tables]

Comment: Short answer is yes, probably.  But, um, DDL for the tables?  DML for the data?  Copy of the query you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming your database is Oracle.

```
      SELECT
         "Step"
        ,"StepName"
        ,"A1"
        ,"A2"
        ,"A3"
        ,"A4"
        ,"A5"
        ,"B3"
        ,"B8"
        ,"B9"
        ,"Interval"
  FROM
        (
        SELECT
               Session_Table."IDNum"
              ,Data_Table."Step"
              ,Data_Table."StepName"
              ,Data_Table."Data"
              ,Data_Table."Interval"
        FROM Session_Table
              --
              JOIN Data_Table
                    ON  Session_Table."xUniqueKey" = Data_Table."xUniqueKey"
        )
  PIVOT
        (
        MAX("Data")
        FOR "IDNum" IN
              (
               'A1'       AS "A1"
              ,'A2'       AS "A2"
              ,'A3'       AS "A3"
              ,'A4'       AS "A4"
              ,'A5'       AS "A5"
              ,'B3'       AS "B3"
              ,'B8'       AS "B8"
              ,'B9'       AS "B9"
              )
        )
  ;
```